# How to pass a title through the helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby on Rails

I am trying to pass a **title** through the helper.

application_helper.rb

```
def utm_url(item)
  if @user.utm.blank?
    item
  else
    item+'?utm_campaign='+item.title
  end
end
```

feed_item.html.erb

`<%= utm_url(feed_item[:link_url]) %>`

user.rb

```
def user_activity
    activity_items = []

    items.each do |item|
      activity_item = {}
      activity_item[:id] = item.id
      activity_item[:url] = item
      activity_item[:title] = item.title
      activity_item[:link_url] = item.url

      activity_items << activity_item
    end

    activity_items.sort_by! { |activity_item| activity_item[:position] }
    activity_items
  end
```

Comment: Whats the problem you are getting? Is there any errors or?

Comment: @Nezir Yes, undefined method `title' for #<String:0x00007fa9399d1108>

Comment: There are much better ways than string concatenation to programatically create paths / urls - use the URI module and `Hash#to_query` from ActivesSupport.

Comment: And instead of using `items.each` and mutating an external variable you can just use `items.map do ... end` to return a new array.

Comment: What is the value here feed_item[:link_url]

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `link_url` string to the helper (it was `item.url` previously), that's why you can't use `title` method on it.

If I understood correctly, your user `has_many :items`. You don't need to convert them to array of hashes `user_activity`, just use all advantages of ActiveRecord.

```
def utm_url(item, utm) 
  # don't use instance variables in helpers, 
  # when project gets bigger it hard to say where they did come from 

  # use early return instead of if/else when possible   
  return item.url if utm.blank?

  item.url + '?utm_campaign=' + item.title
end

<% @user.items.order(position: :asc).each do |item| %>
  <%= utm_url(item, @user.utm) %>
<% end %>
```